# Magento 1.9.2 Cannot place order and update order data in Paypal Express checkout method

Tags: checkout, paypal-express

Hi Magento StackExchange,

I have an issue in Magento 1.9.2, after I activated "PayPal Payments Advanced (Includes Express Checkout)" in System - Configuration - Payment Methods.

I test to buy some items, go to check out page, and choose PayPal Express. The site redirect me to PayPal to login. After insert my email and password, PayPal redirects me back to Review Order page in my Magento Site. I get stuck in Review Order, "Place Order" and "Update Order data" button is clickable but no response.

I have already activated the Log feature from Magento Admin, but there is no error or warning in system.log.

I also tried to "Skip Review Order", but after I get redirected back to my Magento site from PayPal Page, the Review Order Page keeps loading until connection time out.

Is there anyone can give me so advise to fix this issue?